# Find the Inverse Modulus using Euclid's algorithm

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

I asked this before, but unfortunately, I didnt know the methods, nor was the questions phrased properly.

Find the inverse of $4258 \pmod{147}$ Using Euclidean Extended Algorithm.

**Begin By Stating the remainders (Euclid's Algorithm):**

$4258 = 28(147) + 142$

$147 = 1(142) + 5$

$142 = 28(5) + 2$

$5 = 2(2) + 1$

Then BACK substitution starting with $1$:

$1 = 5 - 2\cdot 2$

$1 = 5 - 2\cdot \bigg(142 - 28(5)\bigg ) = -279 + 2\cdot 28(5)$

$1 = -279 + 2\cdot 28\bigg( 147 - 142  \bigg)$

$1 = -279 + 56 \cdot \bigg( 147 - 4258 + 28(147)  \bigg)$

But how would I proceed?

Comment: The method described [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/765333/242) is easier and less error-prone.

Answer (score 1):

In your back substitution you're collapsing some things too much.

In the second back-sub line you should have $1$ as a combination of $5$ and $142$.  That is $$1=5-2\cdot\left(142-28(5)\right)=5\cdot(57)-142\cdot(2)$$.

In your next line you should sub in $5=147-142$ and get $1$ as a combination of $147$ and $142$.

And so on.

Comment: Let me understand something. For Euclid's algorithm, I start with what? $4258$ or $147$?  I have seen some starting with $m$ where $\pmod{m}$ but otherwise as well? how would I begin?

Comment: You should get the same answer either way.  It's a little quicker to start with the larger number.

Comment: So then: If you get: 4258 = x(quotient) + remainder the next step is: quotient = x(remainder) + remainer_2 ??

Comment: Your section 'Begin by stating the remainders' is a good set up.

Comment: Okay, so I do this then: $4258 = 147(z) + R_1$ Then: $z = R_1(y) + R_2$ .... ?

Comment: @Amad27: Your second step should be $147=R_1\cdot y+R_2$--just like you have it set up in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Actually *each* remainder in the euclidean algorithm satisfies Bézout's identity. Let's start with $r_0=4258, r_1=147$. If $r_{i+1} $ is the remainder at the $i$-th step (dividing $r_{i-1}$ by $r_i$), write $r_i=u_i \cdot 4258+v_i\cdot147$. Let $q_i$ be the corresponding quotient. The algorithm translates into the relations:
$$u_{i+1}=u_{i-1}-q_iu_i,\qquad v_{i+1}=v_{i-1}-q_iv_i$$
These relations allow for computing progressively all Bézout's coefficients without having to revert back. This is the *Extended Euclidean Algorithm*. Here is how it goes in the present case:

$$    \begin{array}[t]{r@{\qquad}r@{\qquad}r@{\qquad}r}
   r_i &u_i &v_i & q_i\\
   \hline
  4258 & 1 & 0 & \\
  147 & 0 & 1 & 28\\
     \hline
 142 & 1 & -28 & 1\\
 5 & -1 & 29 & 28 \\
2 & 29 & -840 & 2 \\
 1 & -59 & 1709 \\
     \hline
    \end{array} $$

So $-59\times4258+1709\times 147=1$, which implies $4258^{-1}=-59=88 \bmod 147$.

Answer (score 0):

**The Algorithm:**

- Input: $n=147,a=4258$
- Set $x_1=1$
- Set $x_2=0$
- Set $y_1=0$
- Set $y_2=1$
- Set $r_1=n$
- Set $r_2=a$
- Repeat until $r_2=0$:

  - Set $r_3=r_1\bmod{r_2}$
  - Set $q_3=\lfloor\frac{r_1}{r_2}\rfloor$
  - Set $x_3=x_1-{q_3}\cdot{x_2}$
  - Set $y_3=y_1-{q_3}\cdot{y_2}$
  - Set $x_1=x_2$
  - Set $x_2=x_3$
  - Set $y_1=y_2$
  - Set $y_2=y_3$
  - Set $r_1=r_2$
  - Set $r_2=r_3$
- If $y_1>0$ then output $y_1$
- Otherwise output $y_1+n$

---

**C-Implementation:**

```
int Inverse(int n,int a)
{
    int x1 = 1;
    int x2 = 0;
    int y1 = 0;
    int y2 = 1;
    int r1 = n;
    int r2 = a;

    while (r2 != 0)
    {
        int r3 = r1%r2;
        int q3 = r1/r2;
        int x3 = x1-q3*x2;
        int y3 = y1-q3*y2;

        x1 = x2;
        x2 = x3;
        y1 = y2;
        y2 = y3;
        r1 = r2;
        r2 = r3;
    }

    return y1>0? y1:y1+n;
}

int result = Inverse(147,4258); // 88
```