# Problems with finding inverse by using gcd

Tags: inverse, gcd-and-lcm

I´ve tried to solve this problem, but i think i need some help from you guys.

In my textbook it is written that the inverse of 35 mod 3 is 2, i get that the inverse is 2, but how do you find it by using gcd? This is what i´ve done so far:

gcd(35,3)

35 = 11 * 3 + 2

3 = 1 * 2 + 1

2 = 1 * 2

1 = 3 - 1 * 2 = 3 - (35 - 11 * 3)

= -1 * 35 + 12 * 3

Shouldn´t the inverse be -1 or 12? How do i get 2?

And the same goes for the inverse of 30 mod 11. After finding the gcd, i end up with: -4 * 30 + 11 * 11. The book says that the inverse i 7, but i only get -4 and 11.

Hope someone can help me, Thanks!

Comment: $\!\bmod 3\!:\ 35\equiv -1\,\Rightarrow\, 35^{-1}\equiv (-1)^{-1}\equiv -1\equiv 2.\,$ You don't need ext. Euclid for something that simple, but here is a [much simpler form](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/765333/242) of the ext. Euclidean algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have found $$1 = -1(35)+12(3)$$

Taking modulo $3$.

$$1\equiv (-1)(35) \pmod{3}$$

$-1 \pmod{3}$ is the inverse.

Note that $-1 \equiv 2 \pmod{3}$.

Comment: Thanks, i finally get it!!

Comment: But does this mean that only 2 is the inverse and not -1 and 12?

Comment: $-1$ is equivalent to $2 \pmod{3}$, hence we can say that $-1$ is an inverse as well. $12$ is not an inverse.

Comment: You can think of one person describing $2:40$pm as $20$ minutes before $3$pm, they are equivalent.