# Can you please solve $7^{-1} \mod 480$ using extended Euclidean Algorithm?. Kindly show the steps till end

Tags: modular-arithmetic, inverse, cryptography

I am solving RSA algorithm wherein I have to find d by finding $7$ inverse modulo $480$. Please help in solving till end using extended euclidean algorithm

Using extended Euclidean Algorithm for finding inverse as follows:

$$480 = 7(68) + 4$$
$$68  = 4(17) + 0$$

Now, I am getting remainder 0 here. How shall I proceed ahead after this first step

Comment: " Please solve using extended euclidean algorithm and show all steps till end."  that's a very unreasonable request.  More reasonable would be help to get you started or a rough outline

Comment: $\frac{7}{480}=[0;68,1,1,3]$ and $[0;68,1,1]=\frac{2}{137}$ imply $$7\cdot 137-2\cdot 480 = -1,$$ hence the inverse of $7\pmod{480}$ is given by $-137\equiv 343\pmod{480}$.

Comment: A more efficient technique is probably to find $7^{-1}\pmod{32},\pmod{3},\pmod{5}$, then invoke the Chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/765333/242) for a very convenient form of the Extended Euclidean Algorithm.

Comment: @Jack Unlikely - it's rare that CRT is more efficient than the Extended Euclidean Algorithm, e.g. it took me $10$ seconds of mental arithmetic in my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$480 = 7*68 + 4$ so $4 = 480 - 7*68$

$7 = 4 + 3$ so $3 = 7-4$

$4 = 3 + 1$ so $1 = 4 - 3$

So $1 = 4-3=$

$(480 - 7*68) - (7-4)=$

$(480-7*68) - (7-(480 - 7*68))=$

> $(480-7*68) -(7*69 - 480)=$
>  $2*480 - 137*7$

=====

So how do you solve $7k \equiv 1 \pmod{480}$?

Comment: Can you please solve till end

Comment: Yes, I can.  But I won't.  If  $1 = 2*480 - 137*7$ then $-137*7 \equiv 1\pmod {480}$.

Comment: @firstlast You'll find it much easier (and less error prone) to use the method I linked in a comment on your question (similar to the method in Doug's answer).

Comment: Yes.  I have to agree with Bill and Doug about the ease of their methods.  This was a simple case but the errors one usually has..... (#@%*)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I do it and keep myself organized

$\begin {array}{crl}
\times480&\times 7\\ 
1&0&480\\
0&1&7\\
0&68&476\\
1&-68&4\\
2&-136&8\\
2&-137&1
\end{array}$

Number in the first column, I multiply by 480.  The number in the second column, I multiply by 7.  The third column is their sum.

I do what are effectively matrix row operations to the right column as far as it will go.

$480\times2 + (-137\times 7) = 1$

$-137\equiv 343 \equiv 7^{-1}\pmod{480} $

Worth noting:

$343 = 7^3\\
7^4\equiv 1\pmod{480}$

Answer (score 1):

By [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1117280/242) $\,\ \overbrace{7^{-1}_{480} \equiv \dfrac{1-480(\color{#c00}{480^{-1}_7})}7}^{\rm\large inverse\ reciprocity}\equiv \dfrac{1-480(\color{#c00}2)}7\equiv -137,\ $ by $\bmod 7\!:\ \color{#c00}{\dfrac{1}{480}}\equiv \dfrac{8}4\equiv\color{#c00} 2$

Comment: This is essentially a special case (single step) of the Extended Euclidean Algorithm that is more convenient in certain cases.

Answer (score 0):

My computation of the gcd of $480$ and $7$ in tabular form:

$$
\begin{matrix}
480 & -  & 1 & 0\\  
 7 & 68 & 0 & 1\\ 
 4 & 1 & 1 & -68\\ 
 3 & 1 & -1 & 69\\  
 1 & - & 2 & -137\\ 
\end{matrix}$$

(where the second column has the quotients $q$, and we subtract $q$ times the row of two after it from the row of $2$ above it, for the last two columns. We stop when we reach divisibility as with $1$ and $3$.
So we get $$1 = 2 \cdot 480 + (-137) \cdot 7$$

which we take modulo $480$ and get $$7^{-1} \equiv -137 \equiv 343 \pmod{480}$$

So, e.g. when in RSA we have $\phi(n)=480$ and $e=7$ we take $d=343$.